# How to replace boolean field with a constant value using ASM

Tags: java

I want to transform a field of a class to be effectively a constant. I'm using ASM 5.0.3.

Here is the test class I have:

```
public class BytecodeUtilsTest {

  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeClass(){
    String replaceFieldClassName = "com.mypackage.ClassWithFieldToReplaceWithConstant";
    String replaceFieldClassNameAsPath = replaceFieldClassName.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
    // standard code to redefine class (inspired by ASM FAQ http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html, sec. 5)
    ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream stream = contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(replaceFieldClassNameAsPath);
    byte[] classBytes;
    try {
      classBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);

      // here is the interesting part
      byte[] patchedClassBytes = BytecodeUtils.patch(classBytes, "_fieldToReplace", true);

      Reflection.invoke(contextClassLoader, "defineClass", Class.class,
              new Class[]{String.class, byte[].class, int.class, int.class},
              new Object[]{replaceFieldClassName, patchedClassBytes, 0, patchedClassBytes.length});
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }    
  }

  @Test
  public void testFieldReplace(){
    Assert.assertTrue(new ClassWithFieldToReplaceWithConstant().getFieldToReplace());
    Assert.assertTrue(new ClassWithFieldToReplaceWithConstant()._fieldToReplace);
  }
}
```

Here is the test class to update:

```
public class ClassWithFieldToReplaceWithConstant {
  boolean _fieldToReplace;

  public boolean getFieldToReplace() {
    return _fieldToReplace;
  }
}
```

And here is the patcher:

```
public class BytecodeUtils {
  public static byte[] patch(byte[] bytecode, final String fieldToReplace, final boolean value) {
    ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(bytecode);
    final ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(classReader, 0);
    ClassVisitor classVisitor = new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM4, classWriter) {
      @Override
      public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        return new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM4, super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions)) {
          @Override
          public void visitFieldInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) {
            if (opcode == Opcodes.GETFIELD && name.equals(fieldToReplace)) {
              mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.POP);
              mv.visitInsn(value ? Opcodes.ICONST_1 : Opcodes.ICONST_0);
            } else {
              super.visitFieldInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
            }
          }
        };
      }
    };
    classReader.accept(classVisitor, 0);
    return classWriter.toByteArray();
  }    
}
```

The problem is test fails at the second assert. So if I use getter, it returns `true`as expected, but if I read field directly it returns `false`. That's quite unexpected considering the fact that getter yields `INVOKEVIRTUAL` instruction and field read yields `GETFIELD` which is updated by invocation of `visitInsn` method.

What am I doing wrong and how to make direct field access return `true`?

Comment: You would have to patch the using class where the GETFIELD access happens. Can't you set the field to true and make it final? There seem to be no handled setters.

Comment: @JoopEggen "You would have to patch the using class where the GETFIELD access happens" - yes, thank you. That simple thought slipped my mind. And you're right - the closest thing I could do here is to replace one field with another field which has the default value I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second assert to work you need to patch BytecodeUtilsTest, not ClassWithFieldToReplaceWithConstant, since bytecode instruction to read field for the second case is actually in the BytecodeUtilsTest#testFieldReplace method.

Getter case works fine since instruction to read the field is inside the getter body, i.e, inside the ClassWithFieldToReplaceWithConstant class.

If in real scenario field is private, this code should be fine (since there will be no access to the field from outside of the class field is declared in). Otherwise, you will have to patch every class which reads or writes to this field.